# Sending E-mails

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, smtp, credentials

I am trying to send e-mails with VB.net and I have a template for the code but I don't understand a few lines.

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
mail.From = New MailAddress("YOURusername@gmail.com")
mail.To.Add("TOADDRESS")
```

As far as I understand, mail.From is the sender's name, and mail.to.add is the person I am sending to. What does `smtpServer.Credentials` do?

I deduce that `SmtpServer.Credentials` is the only one that requires a password so that will be the account the e-mail will be sent from. But then what is the point of `mail.From`? What happens if I put different e-mails in `credentials` and `mail.From`.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`SmtpServer.Credentials` must be used only if your provider needs authentication to send email.
You can read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials.aspx)

> Some SMTP servers require that the client be authenticated before the
>   server will send e-mail on its behalf. To use your default network
>   credentials, you can set the `UseDefaultCredentials` to **true** instead of
>   setting this property. If the `UseDefaultCredentials` property is set to
>   **false**, then the value set in the **Credentials** property will be used for
>   the credentials when connecting to the server. If the
>   `UseDefaultCredentials` property is set to **false** and the **Credentials**
>   property has not been set, then mail is sent to the server
>   anonymously.

`From` is used by receiving client as the address to send replies to.

Comment: So if I authenticate the credentials using my E-mail address and password. But then in mail.From write BillGates@Microsoft.com, what is stopping me from spoofing Bill's e-mail?

Comment: @PejmanPoh: Nothing if receiving client has not something that warns user. Remember anyway that when you receive an email you can check headers: in this case you see that email is sent from your real account and not from Bill Gates one!!

Answer (score 0):

mail.From is used for display purpose. When the receive hit Reply it will add mail.From in the display name and SmtpServer.Credentials in the email address. You can alternatively also set the Reply-To address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...`SmtpServer.Credentials` will take the login credentials that it sends the email from that id-password...but it also provides the feature that you can add any email id in `mail.From` so that will be shown in the `From` part (Display purpose) of the mailbox. so it only shows that id in `From` part but the actual mail comes from the one you define in credentials.

I think this will be helpful to you..!!